# Unable to send data Bluetooth weight machine using flutter_bluetooth_serial

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Currently I'm working in a small app connected with a device through Bluetooth with flutter and flutter_bluetooth_serial package.

Can connect with Bluetooth device and also received data from weight machine, But not able to send data into Bluetooth weight machine. any body can give me Idea?

Comment: Please add your code for connecting to the device and what you've tried to send data to it - we can't help without the code

Comment: here is my code : List<int> list = '50'.codeUnits;
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
    connection.output.add(bytes);
    await connection.output.allSent;
    setState(() {
      _deviceState = 1; // device on
    });

Comment: @Moloy you can use edit button at the bottom of your question and add more information and code about your question